# How to access API secrets from Next.js in AWS Amplify

Tags: build, next.js, environment-variables, aws-amplify, api-key

I am very confused regarding how to set and access API secrets in a Next.js app within an AWS Amplify project.

**The scenario is**: I have a private API key that fetches data from an API. Obviously, this is a secret key and I don't want to share it in my github repo or the browser. I create a .env.local file and place my secret there.

```
API_KEY="qwerty123"
```

I am able to access this key in my code through using `process.env.API_KEY`

Here is an example fetch request with that API Key: `https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?${parkCode}&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`

This works perfectly when I run `yarn dev` and `yarn build -> yarn start`

This is the message I get when I run `yarn start`

```
next start
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /Users/tmo/Desktop/Code/projects/visit-national-parks/.env.local
```

The env is loaded and able to be called on my local machine.

### However,

When I push this code to github and start the Build process in AWS Amplify, the app builds, but the API fetch calls do not work. I get a ````500 Server Error`````

This is what I have done to try and solve this issue:

1. **Added my API_KEY in the `Environment variables` tab in Amplify**

[image]
2. Update my `Build settings`

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - API_KEY=${API_KEY} '#Added my API_KEY from the environment variables tab in Amplify`
        - yarn run build
```

I am not sure what else to do. After building the app again, I still get `500 server error`

Here is the [live amplify app](https://main.d1tqqy4zlrfx94.amplifyapp.com/park/cakr) with the server error.

Comment: Do you know for sure the issue comes from the `API_KEY` environment variable? Did you check AWS Amplify logs for the error you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

We're working on something similar right now. Our dev designed it so it reads an .env file.

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - echo API_KEY=$API_KEY >.env
        - echo OTHERKEY=$OTHER_KEY >> .env
        - yarn run build
```

We were able to pick it up and pass it to AWS' DynamoDB Client SDK.

Not sure if it's your call or not, but yarn can be fickle in our Amplify projects sometimes, so we usually resort to using npm if it starts acting up.

Comment: This worked for me for passing Environment Variables that I defined for the app through the Amplify console. Though for sensitive values I think something more beyond this is needed. Perhaps there's a way to read a secret value out of something like AWS secrets manager, and write it out to the .env file?

Comment: Although I haven’t tried it, a project that’s a monorepo can achieve this. You set the secrets at the API level. However, this isn’t supported for pure front end projects which makes sense anyway even without Amplify.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine for non-secrets by passing needed configuration through environment variables. But I would recommend a secrets store vs. placing secrets using env vars. Examples for secrets management are Hashicorp Vault and AWS Secrets Manager (not free of course). The other advantage of using a secrets manager is you can easily rotate them or regenerate them and track what is accessing them.

That said you can read about next.js environment variable load order [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order).

tl;dr Environment variables are looked up in the following places, in order, stopping once the variable is found.

- process.env
- .env.$(NODE_ENV).local
- .env.local (Ignored if NODE_ENV is test)
- .env.$(NODE_ENV)
- .env

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on how to read the values out of Secrets Manager / Vault in order to make them available? Would you read them using the appropriate CLI during build time, and then write them out to the .env file?